# Swagger: Where to set an API-Key for Authorization

Tags: annotations, swagger, swagger-php

I use Nelmio APi Doc 3.4. Swagger.
I want to use an apiKey authorization for my api.
I set the configuration in `nelmio_api_doc.yaml`:

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
            schemes: [https]
            securityDefinitions:
                app_api_key:
                    type: apiKey
                    description: 'App Api Key'
                    name: Authorization
                    in: header
            security:
                - app_api_key: []
```

An in my Controller I set the parameter in the annotations:

```
....
@SWG\Parameter(
     *         name="Authorization",
     *         in="header",
     *         required=true,
     *         type="string",
     *         default="PUT HERE THE KEY",
     *         description="Authorization"
     *     )
*/
public function getProductAction()
{
....
}
```

But where do I set my ApiKey? For example I have an apiKey "abc123" and I want to check it against the insert key?
I dont understand where this function is. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the specific annotation for security authorizations:

```
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation as Nelmio;

/**
 * @Nelmio\Security(name="app_api_key"),
 * @SWG\Get()
 */
public function getProductAction()
{
    //...
}
```